# After a basic Postfix install is there a method to determine if it can receive emails?

Tags: postfix

**Environment:** Postfix 3.3, CentOS 8, Digital Ocean Droplet

After Postfix is installed, some basic configuration parameters have been set and a few DNS records are created it's easy to see if Postfix can send email to the outside world with `sendmail`.

```
$ sendmail user@example.com
hello world
this is my message
.
```

At this point (without Dovecot installed) is there an easy way to determine if Postfix can receive emails as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could do the same, but sending to a local account. Say your domain is: example.com, then from the server:

```
$ sendmail user@example.com
hello world
this is my message
.
```

The message *should* be delivered to that account, it depends on your configuration.

From outside the server that should also work, if you set the MX record.

The message will be at `/var/mail/username`.

Comment: It worked perfect!  In fact I replied from my Gmail account and a minute later checked the  `/var/mail/username` file and saw the message.  Awesome!  Sorry I should have mentioned that I had already set up DNS.

Comment: You can't use local `sendmail` to test this, because it doesn't test whether the `smtpd` is configured correctly to receive mail. See http://www.postfix.org/OVERVIEW.html#receiving